# Keeping Corners of a Rectangle accurate

Tags: java, list, sorting, rect

I am trying to keep the corners of a rectangle accurate as shown below. Given a list of 4 points in no specified order, how would I go about sorting this list in Java?  I do not have access to the drawn shape object, but I do have the center point.

A Point having an X and Y property, and the first index of the sorted list being A, and the last index being D.
[image: diagram]

I have tried this, but when rotating the list gets out of order.

```
Collections.sort(corners, new Comparator<GeoPoint>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(GeoPoint o1, GeoPoint o2) {
                    if (o1.getLongitude() < o2.getLongitude()) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (o1.getLatitude() < o2.getLatitude()) {
                        return 1;
                    } else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I will just use the quadrants of the rectangle.Based on the angle, A is 270-360, B is 0-90, C is 90-180, D is 180-270

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it.  If you rotate that rectangle PI radians, all the corners will have the same coordinate values but the actual labeled corner would be different.

Why not create a class

```
class LabeledPoint {
   int id;
   Point point;
} 
// or perhaps

class LabeledPoint extends Point {
   int id;
}
```

If each rectangle is composed of a `LabeledPoint` and you rotate that point in conjunction with the other points, you can then sort the list of corner points using the id.

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I am not able to do that because I only get the list of Points. I don't really care if its the same corner, I only care that the corners are ordered in that fashion. Some times with the code I had, the list would get out of order. Instead of ABCD, it would be BACD for example. I just need that arrangement of corners.

Comment: Rotating a list of points does not change their order.  so if specified them in locations A,B,C,D, then the list would still maintain those altered points at the same index.